# Grok pattern for [Mon Jan 04 08:36:12 2021]

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, datestamp

I am working on shipping some logs to elasticsearch using logstash. I am unable to figure out the grok pattern for [Mon Jan 04 08:36:12 2021] .The format is **Day Month Date Time Year** Help and Suggestions are most welcome.

Log - `[Mon Jan 04 08:36:12 2021]`
Grok I tried - `\[%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{TIME:time} %{YEAR:year}]`
Result Expected - `Day:Mon Month:Jan Date:04 Hour:08 Minute:36 Second:12 Year:2021`

Comment: Have you tried the [default Grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well, I tried something like this - %{DAY MONTH DATE TIME YEAR:mytimestamp}  and it didn't work . Thats the reason , i posted it here .

Comment: Please add what you tried to the question, and explain what behavior you observed, and what is expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Added !

Comment: It looks like you forgot the `%{MONTHDAY}`, use `\[%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME:time} %{YEAR:year}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the `%{MONTHDAY}` in between the month and time variables.

You can use

```
\[%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME:time} %{YEAR:year}]
```

[Grok pattern](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) list used:

- `DAY (?:Mon(?:day)?|Tue(?:sday)?|Wed(?:nesday)?|Thu(?:rsday)?|Fri(?:day)?|Sat(?:urday)?|Sun(?:day)?)`
- `MONTH \b(?:[Jj]an(?:uary|uar)?|[Ff]eb(?:ruary|ruar)?|[Mm](?:a|ä)?r(?:ch|z)?|[Aa]pr(?:il)?|[Mm]a(?:y|i)?|[Jj]un(?:e|i)?|[Jj]ul(?:y|i)?|[Aa]ug(?:ust)?|[Ss]ep(?:tember)?|[Oo](?:c|k)?t(?:ober)?|[Nn]ov(?:ember)?|[Dd]e(?:c|z)(?:ember)?)\b`
- `MONTHDAY (?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])`
- `TIME (?!<[0-9])%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}(?::%{SECOND})(?![0-9])`

  - `HOUR (?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])`
  - `MINUTE (?:[0-5][0-9])`
  - `SECOND (?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?)`
- `YEAR (?>\d\d){1,2}`